# Getting omniauth-facebook (and omniauth-oauth2) to work on Rails 2.3.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, authentication, omniauth

I'm trying to get the `omniauth-facebook` gem working in my Rails 2.3.4 application, but it depends on `omniauth-oauth2`, which in turn depends on `rack ~> 1.2`. When I try requiring it in my application I get this error message:

```
[Dev]> require 'omniauth-facebook'
Gem::LoadError: can't activate rack (~> 1.2, runtime) for ["oauth2-0.8.0", "omniauth-oauth2-1.1.0", "omniauth-facebook-1.4.1"], already activated rack-1.0.1 for []
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:233:in `activate'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:249:in `activate'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:248:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:248:in `activate'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:249:in `activate'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:248:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:248:in `activate'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:249:in `activate'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:248:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems.rb:248:in `activate'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from (irb):1
```

This error is caused by the fact that `actionpack` 2.3.4 requires `rack ~> 1.0.0`, and so by the time `omniauth-oauth2` gets around to requiring `~> 1.2`, `1.0.1` has already been loaded and it blows up

How can I get around this problem without upgrading my Rails version? (Would using an older version of `omniauth-facebook` work?)

Comment: nope lol (think i might have to upgrade to 2.3.8...)